# Clipboard can copy a few words?

Tags: c#

I'm weak in English so I hope you will understand this.

I learned yesterday that Clipboard is copy.

```
//textBox1.Text = "My name is not exciting";
Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
textBox2.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

This code copies your everything from the textbox1 and paste it in textbox2 right?

So it's possible to copy only a few words from textbox1 and paste it in textbox2?

If you don't understand, I'm want copy only a few words not all the line.

Even if this high level code still bring  me :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using the clipboard as opposed to a variable?

Comment: assign textBox1.Text to a string and do string operations like substring to get only the desired subset and give it to Clipboard.SetText(copiedString)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel, the substring method is a good one to use. You simply tell it where you want to take a piece of your text and it will create a new string of just that.

```
textBox1.Text = "MY name is not exciting";
        //pretend you only want "not exciting" to show
        int index = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("not");//get the index of where "not" shows up so you can cut away starting on that word.

        string partofText = textBox1.Text.Substring(index);//substring uses the index (in   this case, index of "not") to take a piece of the text. 

        Clipboard.SetText(partofText);
        textBox2.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
```

Comment: So the line starts in "not"?   Or it cuts out the word?

Comment: it starts with "not". You can use substring to find the spot of a whole word or just one letter--but since n was already used in the sentence, I used "not." Technically, it just finds the spot of the n in not. It should read "not exciting"--that's what it did when I ran it. It starts there, and unless you specify how many spaces long you want it to cut out, it will cut out from that point to the end of the string.

Comment: THANKS! But I can do it also will stop in the middle?   like textBox1.Text.IndexOf("name"); And it stops at "not"?   never mind, I'm do this textBox1.Text.LastIndexOf("not"); textBox1.Text.Substring(index, index2); , it's work :)

Comment: Yes. substring can take either one or two indexes. With two, it takes where you want to start it and how long you want it to go. So find both indexes, find the difference between them, and the put in to substring where you want it to start and that difference. It will give you the string.

Comment: int start = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("name");

            int end = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("not");

            int difference = end - start;

            string partofText = textBox1.Text.Substring(start,     difference); //this gives you "name is ". Add 3 to the difference to get "name is not".

Answer (score 1):

`Clipboard.GetText();` will return the raw copied elements.

What you can do is save them to some variable:

```
string text = Clipboard().GetText();
```

Then do something with `text`, to get the elements you need:

```
textBox2.Text = text.Substring(0, 10); // An example.
```

---

The main idea to take away from this is, `GetText()` will give you a string. It's up to you to slice and dice that string any way you see fit and then make use of the results.

Comment: possible can do this starts to copy a specific word? I mean by words

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Clipboard for this. Your user won't like that ;)

Just create a variable like this:

```
string box1Content = textBox1.Text;
textBox2.Text = boxContent;
```

You can even skip that variable.

If you really want to use the clipboard, your way is doing that.

For just getting some text out of the textbox you can either use substring or regular expressions. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To my mind is better idea to take selected text from text box.

I'm not sure witch kind of text box you are using but so show example on WPF you should use [TextBox.SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectedtext.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

I like linq. :-)

This is a example for splitting the string, enumerable it and concats in one:

```
textBox1.Text = "My name is not exciting";

int firstWord = 2;
int lastWord = 4;

string[] wordList = textBox1.Text.Split(new[] { ' ', '.', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string newText = string.Concat(wordList.Where((word, count) => count >= firstWord - 1 && count < lastWord).Select(w => w + " ")).TrimEnd();

Clipboard.SetText(newText);
textBox2.Text = Clipboard.GetText();

// Result: "name is not"
```

Edit: and without Clipboard you can use simply this Line

```
textBox2.Text = newText;
```